# MySQL search for non-ascii charcter NOT working as intended with LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, character-encoding

I have in my MySQL database a table with a varchar field that has utf8_general_ci collation. My problem is that when I do a query like

```
SELECT title FROM node WHERE title LIKE "%ñ%"
```

in PHP it returns all the titles that have "n" and "ñ" in them. I tried to do the same query from the terminal in linux and I did not get any results. I don't know if it's from the lack of unicode support in the terminal or not.

*How can I filter my query to display results that contain the expression with the exact characters I want? Is it a PHP to MySQL transmission problem? I have PHP 5.3 and MySQL 5.1.*

**PS:**

I know

```
SELECT title FROM node WHERE title LIKE "%n%"
```

returns the same results (with "n" and "ñ") as the query above, I don't mind that. I just want to be able to filter expressions with unicode charcatrs that match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, MySQL tries to be helpful by treated equivalent characters as equal.  This includes accents on characters.  There is a section of the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html) devoted to this.

Try using the `binary` operator:

```
SELECT title FROM node WHERE title LIKE BINARY '%ñ%'
```

Comment: I had a feeling `BINARY` would come into play.